# How to empty a PST in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to empty an archive PST file so that I can use it to store freshly archived stuff. I've already backed up the PST.

I want to do this so that I'm not carrying years and years of old e-mails with me everywhere; one year is quite enough.

I know that I can simply delete the PST but then I would have to figure out how to create a new one and point Outlook at it. Also, then I'm sure Outlook will complain the next time I start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could simply close the archives file inside Outlook, move it, and then run the Outlook archiving tool.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've already backed up the PST, emptying it in Outlook and compacting it should be equivalent to creating a new one.

### How to Manually Start PST Compaction

- Delete any items that you do not want to keep (in your case delete *everything*), and then empty the **Deleted Items** folder
- Click the **File** tab on the Ribbon, and then click the **Info** tab on the menu
- Click the **Accounts Settings** tab, and then click on **Accounts Settings** again
- Click the **Data Files** tab
- Click to select your **Personal** folder, and then click **Settings**
- On the **General** tab, click **Compact Now**
- Click **OK**, and then click **Close**

### How to Manually Start OST Compaction

- Delete any items that you do not want to keep (in your case delete *everything*), and then empty the **Deleted Items** folder
- Click the **File** tab on the Ribbon, and then click the **Info** tab on the menu
- Click the **Accounts Settings** tab, and then click **Account Settings** again
- In the list, select **Microsoft Exchange Server**, and then click **Change**
- Click **More Settings**
- On the **Advanced** tab, click **Offline Folder File Settings**
- Click **Compact Now**

<sub>[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289987)</sub>

Comment: This will reduce the size of the .pst/.ost file but it won't clean out all the old emails. I think the OP just wants a fresh PST for this year.

Comment: @Kyle: If you read the first step, it says you need to ***Delete** all unwanted items first*. If you delete everything in a PST and then compact, that's as good as starting afresh according to me. Otherwise the OP can always do what was suggested in the other answer, i.e. create a new PST.

Comment: Yeah I read that part... which is why I commented. I guess if the point of this is to create a fresh PST in the most time consuming way possible then you're right, effectively it will be a new PST if you sift through it and delete everything then compact it.

Comment: I apologize I read your answer and it gave me the impression you were thinking the OP only wanted some stuff removed. In which case this would be the way to do it.

Comment: @Kyle: No problemo. :) IMO it's not that hard to simply delete the old PST and create a new one, but since the OP wants to avoid that for some reason I guess this is as good a solution as any.

Comment: Fair enough. If that's what OP wants then this is technically correct (the best kind of correct). +1.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest simply creating a new data file....it is quite easy.  Just consult the HELP pages provided in the Outlook application.  It isn't that hard, as I have had to do this a few times off and on in the past year.

Then use that as the archive and delete the old file.

Summary: The specific information is easily readable and available in the M$ Outlook help.

Comment: Why not just add the steps? Even if it's copypasta, just cite your source (help file) and it will make this answer usable for reference.